# how to write Hello Robin. You are currently left with 10 chocolates.?

Tags: python, string, format

```
def main():
    data = ("Robin", 10, "chocolates")
    format_string = None
    print(format_string %data)
    print("Hello %d.You are currently left with %s %d" %(data))
    
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i got runtime error .how to solve this?.Actually i want to print " Hello Robin. Yo are currenty left with 10 chocolates

Answer (score 1):

A f-string based alternative.

```py
def main():
    name, number, obj = ("Robin", 10, "chocolates")
    print(f"Hello {name}.You are currently left with {number} {obj}")

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
def main():
    data = ("Robin", 10, "chocolates")
    print('"Hello {}.You are currently left with {} {}"'.format(*data))
    
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    data = ("Robin", 10, "chocolates")
    print("Hello %s.You are currently left with %d %s" %(data))
    
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The format_string related code is unnecessary for your purposes. You just need to match the format specifiers (%s - string, %d etc) to your data:

```
def main():
    data = ("Robin", 10, "chocolates")
    print("Hello %s.You are currently left with %d %s" %(data))
    
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```